# Can I exclude field from post and put requests but expose it in get in spring-data-rest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I have a model where I have something like this

```
public class Foo {

private int foo;
private int bar;

public setFoo(int foo) {
   bar = someFunction(foo);
}
}
```

So I'd like user to be able to see bar, but not directly affecting it. Is that achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is a getter for `bar`.

```
public int getBar() {
   return bar;
}
```

So it is visible but not changeable.